# change enter to space on dynamic tag plugin

Tags: jquery, tags

We use a dynamic tag plugin. Currently you need to press enter after each word, to create new tag. I need to change this to spacebar instead of enter key.

I looked for keycode 13 and tried changing to 32 but no worky.

Any ideas, heres a fiddle I created

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/tetna/3/

Unminified fiddle.

Comment: why has this been voted down ? jeez

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this much at all, but it seems to work if you simply change the name of the property `13` in the `keys` object to `32`:

```
keys: {  
    8:"backspace", 
    9:"tab", 
    32:"space!", //Changed to 32
    27:"escape!", 
    37:"left", 
    38:"up!", 
    39:"right", 
    40:"down!", 
    46:"delete", 
    108:"numpadEnter" 
}
```

Here's a [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tetna/2/). Note that I've added in the formatting above, since you have pasted the minified plugin code into the fiddle. It would probably be far easier for you to modify the plugin if you used the un-minified code!

Comment: Unfortunately when we press space it repeats last tag typed.